# Is there no usb_find_busses() in the recent libusb version?

Tags: usb, libraries

I referenced from some web pages for developing usb enumeration function with libusb. I've installed libusb-1.0-dev on my linux, but the compiler told me that the *usb_init()* and *usb_find_busses()* are not declared in the libusb.h,  which those introduced by several technical web sites or blogs.

Instead, I found *libusb_init()* and *libusb_get_device_list()* in the header file. So, are the API changed with the newer functions in the recently version of the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`usb_init()` and `usb_find_busses` are part of the older libusb 0.1 API, and shouldn’t be used any more. The libusb 1.0 API was released in 2008, so there’s been plenty of time for 1.0-based tutorials to be written; I recommend you look into that rather than trying to learn the 0.1 API.

See [the libusb web site](http://libusb.info/) for details (the API documentation is unfortunately hosted on SourceForge, so it’s hard to access; but your distribution should have a documentation package containing all the API documentation).

Comment: I'm not able to find any appropriate documentation for this user case.

Comment: @not2qubit which use case? If you’re trying to enumerate USB devices as in the original question, see [`libusb_get_device_list`](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__libusb__dev.html#gac0fe4b65914c5ed036e6cbec61cb0b97).

Comment: Yeah, I see what you say. I was just over eagerly hoping to find/see some example code using these and not only the API function type.